# Xcode Organizer: can not use iPhone (dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed)

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios

When plugging my iPhone in and starting the Xcode organizer, a yellow circle next to the device show me that "This device is busy or otherwise unusable by Xcode."
The Organizer is then processing two files (the second one takes quite a while to finish) and afterwards I get the error message as shown in the screenshot.

I tried to google for that error message ("dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed") but could not find anything useful.
I tried a couple things: repair permissions of my harddrive and run "sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force". Still getting the error message.

I am running iOS 4.2.1 and Xcode 3.2.5. I have not updated Xcode after updating from 4.2 to 4.2.1 (I think).
[image]

The Xcode console is empty but the regular OS X console shows this:

```
1/22/11 10:56:19 PM     Xcode[4187]     Started symbol copying process
1/22/11 10:56:19 PM     Xcode[4187]     Skipped copying file 1 of 2 ("processed" sentinal found)
1/22/11 10:56:19 PM     Xcode[4187]     Skipped processing file 1 of 2 ("processed" sentinal found)
1/22/11 10:56:19 PM     Xcode[4187]     Skipped copying file 2 of 2 ("copied" sentinal found)
1/22/11 10:56:19 PM     Xcode[4187]     Started processing file 2 of 2
1/22/11 10:56:20 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:20 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:20 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:21 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:21 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:22 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:22 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:22 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:23 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:23 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
1/22/11 10:56:23 PM     [0x0-0x4d04d].com.apple.Xcode[4187]     arch already exists in fat dylib
```

This error message is then repeated constantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the help of somebody at the Apple Developer Forums I was able to fix the problem by removing the "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)" folder. Xcode then re-added the symbols automatically and the error disappeared.
For more information see this [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/367667#367667).

Answer (score 55):

Target path to directory has been changed since Xcode 3.

If you have same issue in Xcode 8 then follow next steps:

1. Delete a directory in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`
   that matches the version of the iOS on your device.
2. Restart Xcode.

Source: [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22732)

Comment: Deleting '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/' worked for me. Didn't need to restart XCode though.

Comment: So for Xcode10, deleting this folder first. then doing the below suggestion of unpairing then pairing device again worked.

Comment: I have Xcode 10.2.1 and when I connect my iPhone 11 and follow the above steps but still not working my iPhone 11 has 13.3 iOS version.

Comment: worked like charm!

Answer (score 34):

After all this time I wanna contribute with one more possible solution for this problem...

1. Open Devices and Simulators
2. Right click on your device and select `Unpair Device`
3. Wait until your device ask for trust - this is important.. I noted that if I don´t wait this step the error persists
4. Click on the plus button down... (+).
5. When the next window open, if your iPhone still not appears wait a lit bit.. will appear
6. When your device appear, select it.

One more thing: I changed the version inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport from 10.3 to 10.3.3 - that is "exactly" version on my device, so, observe this too.

Believe in me guys... I bought 2 cables, investigate all links in google, bing, yahoo, books, forums... everything and nothing solves... until this.

Comment: This should be the the accepted fix for the problem.

Comment: Hi Ota, how did you change that to 10.3.3?

Answer (score 28):

For me the approach that worked was the one mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22732) which is:

1. Open Finder and go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`
2. Remove the folder that matches your device and reconnect your phone

Comment: How do you know which folder matches your device?

Comment: iOS version that matches your device. You can find your device OS by checking Organizer.

Answer (score 22):

For Xcode 10.1, iOS 13.3 Below helped me.

Copied from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108917

1. go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.2/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld
2. create empty file if it is not there - .processed_dyld_shared_cache_arm64e
3. restart xcode and enjoy!

Comment: All other solutions didn't worked for me and this solution is worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too for 13.3

Comment: I had a slightly different OS directory "13.3 (17C54)" than the post, but this solution worked fine for me.

Comment: had me worried; took another reboot, but FINALLY I can use this iPhone 11.  Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you! Worked for 13.3 iPhone 11

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth: I encountered this problem when I was out of disk space. It seems that XCode was the first application to 'notice' by throwing this error. After freeing up some disk space everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when disk space was very low on the mac

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after updating to iOS 12.0.1.
I deleted the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/` 12.0.1 version folder but that didn't work. After restarting my iPhone it worked. I noticed that Xcode prepared my phone for debugging again, so it must have messed up the first time around.

Comment: I ran into this issue on iOS 17.1.1, nothing I did worked until I deleted the entire `/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` folder. I tried unpairing, rebooting, using the latest Xcode 15.0.1, rebooting Xcode, and rebooting iPhone. My guess is something was corrupted and needed to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

for xCode 10.1 on High Sierra, you need to create an empty file named :

```
.processed_dyld_shared_cache_arm64e
```

and paste it to:

```
 /Users/{you}/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/{your device version} arm64e/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld
```

make sure that the folder is empty. for me it took couple of time trying and waiting and removing device to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same issue in Xcode 10 (this worked for me using 10 beta 5 and iOS 12 beta 5) the steps are the same except it was necessary to restart the computer (restarting the iOS device, quitting and relaunching Xcode did not work).

1) Quit Xcode

2) Delete folder located at: 
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/ iOS version on target device

3) Restart Computer

You will need to either navigate to the user Library via Terminal or show hidden files in finder.

Toggle hidden files with: command + shift + .(dot)

Answer (score 0):

Move your project to an external hard drive and compiled again This happens when you do not have much space on your machine

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem through this:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0

to sum up , you could:

1. Go to window-devices and simulators
2. Select the unrunable device and right click, then choose unpair
3. now this is the crucial part, your device will ask for trust automatically, dont click trust
4. Focus back to the device panel, left click the + and add the device, click next, it will ask you to tap the "trust" IN THE PANEL
5. Now you can tap the "trust" in your phone, the panel will say phone added successfully
6. run the app again, problem should be solved.

Ref: Link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108917

Answer (score 0):

I spend two days looking for the right answer.

I tried unpairing my device and deleting the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/` but nothing didn't work for me. 
The solution for me was to upgrade my MacOS to the latest version: **Catalina 10.15.1**. 
Then I have downloaded the latest Xcode **11.2.1_GM_Seed**. 
I took the device support folder from the new Xcode and I added to my old Xcode.

I guess the device Support in this [link](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport) has something wrong. 
Because when I used it I got this error: "dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed"

PS: This a solution for those who wants to run their project (written on Swift 4) on a real iPhone (OS 13.2)