# Xcode not recognizing iPhone 5s, dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, device, xcode5

I am trying to run my app on an iPhone 5s. I plug in the device, but its name does not appear among the simulators as an option for Running; instead I just have the generic "iOS Device" option. In the Organizer window, I navigate to my device, which Organizer does recognize as having a valid provisioning profile. But when I click "Use for Development", I get this message:

```
dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed
```

The answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed) seems to be outdated now. They suggested 'removing the "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)" folder.' But that folder is no longer used in Xcode versions after 4.2. I am on Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This folder is now in the Xcode.app bundle.  Open the `Terminal` app on your Mac, then:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
$ ls
     4.2        4.3     5.0     5.1     6.0     6.1     7.0 (11A465)
$ rm -rf "7.0 (11A465)"
```

By the way, if this doesn't work, you might want to consider reinstalling Xcode and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, so I managed to delete "7.0 (11A465)" as you described above, BUT, Xcode did not re-add it when i restarted. I still get the same error with the iPhone 5s. I assume I need to somehow re-add 7.0 as a supported OS in that folder. How do I do that?

Comment: btw, I would +1 your answer but I dont have enough karma yet :(

Comment: @jesseilev I have not run into that scenario before.  You might try rebooting your Mac or running `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force` from the Terminal app.  More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/update_dyld_shared_cache.1.html

Comment: By the way, if this doesn't work, you might want to consider reinstalling Xcode and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Success! I reinstalled Xcode and that worked. Full disclosure, I actually was still on the Xcode5 Preview, and I upgraded to the real Xcode5.

Comment: I tried deleting both 7.0 and 7.1 and it worked.  But the directories were not generated.  Not sure why they are there.

Comment: I tried running just "sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force" from the Terminal app without deleting anything, that fixed the problem for me.