# Processing Symbol Files in Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

When I try to run my Xcode project on my iPhone device, it gives me this pop up.
iPhone is busy: Processing symbol files. If caused for more than 3 quarters of an hour, but nothing got in working state, even the progress bar is still!
[image]

Comment: Did you try disconnecting and reconnecting the phone back?

Comment: disconnect , reconnect, if not solve then restart XCode and it will be solved. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes I've disconnected and reconnected the phone back, but it still seems to give the same thing. In fact, I've also turned off and restarted the mac book.

Comment: now it gives me ... dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

Comment: @JagveerSingh Problem is not solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. Clean Project
2. Remove this folder Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
3. Find your project folder in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and remove
4. Restart Xcode

Comment: This worked for me "Remove this folder Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache"

Answer (score 6):

1.First restart your iPhone and mac

2.Try to use another cable or USB port

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes I've disconnected and reconnected the phone back, but it still seems to give the same thing. In fact, I've also turned off and restarted the mac book.

Comment: It still gives me, in fact on the very first move, as I gonna select the device as the connected one, my iPhone 6s, it suddenly get starts the same this processing symbol files.

Comment: Check This one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed

Answer (score 3):

close xcode and start again 
and its done