# Xcode stuck at "Processing Symbol Files"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode8

When I try to run my app on my device Xcode gets stuck on processing symbol files.

I restarted the machine (I'm using VirtualBox), tried a different USB port, restarted the host computer, cleaned the build folder, tried a different project, updated Xcode to 8.2, tried to use Xcode 7.3 but nothing worked. My device does show in iTunes.

I left iTunes open when I tried to run it on my iPad and then it said "**Unable to copy symbol files** - *unable to read required data from device*"

Xcode 8.2 (latest currently) and iOS 10.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I have solved exactly the same problem. I think the main problem is in VirtualBox USB controller. Go to the settings of your virtual machine, select USB and you will see 'USB Controller 1.1 (OHCI)' by default. You have to select 'USB controller 2.0 (EHCI)'.
I have:
- VirtualBox: 5.1.12r112440 (Qt5.6.2)
- macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with the latest updates.
- XCode 8.2
- iPhone 5, iOS 10.2

Be sure that:
- You have original lightning cable
- You can see your iDevice in iTunes
- Try to restart your MAC and iDevice

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. What I did:

> 1. Make sure all your hardware *(iPhones, iPads ect..)* are all up to date.
> 2. Make sure Xcode and all other software are up to their latest versions.

After you have done both of those, restart your computer and try again.
It **will** take a while for Xcode to processes the index files for the first time, but after these steps above, it should work fine.

Comment: Would using a virtual machine have some influence? (The device works fine in iTunes though) @marquaviousDraggon

Comment: I would argue that making sure the device is "up to date" is a wrong idea: it is important to test software on other than latest version of OS. People keep iphones with old versions of OS for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

1. Clean Project
2. Remove this folder Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
3. Find your project folder in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and remove
4. Restart Xcode

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41829191/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 0):

1.Clean Project
2. Go to window tab , Device and simulator
3.Right click on your device list then click unpair device and reconnect the device.[image]