# Xcode 8.21 (8C1002) stuck processing symbol files for iPhone 6s 10.1.1 (14B100) on VirtualBox

Tags: ios, macos, virtualbox, xcode8

So I've been trying to get xcode working on a VM, using VirtualBox to run macOS Sierra, host machine is Win10, development target is my iPhone 6s. Currently my phone firmware is 10.1.1 (14B100).

I have a project set up in xcode, and my device is recognized in the most recent version of iTunes on my VM, and it is also recognized in XCode. When I attempt to press the play button on my project, I get the loading bar

> "Processing symbol files. Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished."

It's been multiple hours with no success, tried multiple times and read what feels like every question posted about similar issues to no avail.

I have tried:

-Resetting network settings on device

-Plugging cable out & in

-Using Apple certified cable (two different ones tried, two different ports)

-Deleting iOS Device Support folder

-Running the clean project command

-Restarting XCode

-Restarting my VM

-Restarting my host computer

-Confirmed that my Xcode & iTunes are up to date

-Emptying trash can in attempt to create more space

Suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be appreciated, is there any method I can use to negate this need for symbol files? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and got the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211718/xcode-stuck-at-processing-symbol-files) post. So, here it goes:

1. Check if you have the latest version of VirtualBox (and upgrade it if you don't)
2. Install the VirtualBox Extension Pack (so step 3 can work)
3. On Settings->USB select USB 2.0 (VM must be off)

A few notes:

- If the machine does not boot try unplugging the iPhone
- If the iPhone is not detected check if the usb you are using is 2.0 or 3.0 (this should match the VirtualBox setting)

Comment: maybe i overlooked this, but did give up on my attempts and switches to linux so cant actually verify if this is a fix or not, appreciate the response tho