# dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed while trying to run app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios12

I ran into a problem trying to run my app on my iPhone using Xcode. The app builds successfully but returns "dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed" error when trying to run on my iPhone.

[dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zutIU.png)

The problem started when I updated my Xcode and ios to the latest versions i.e 10 and ios 12 respectively.

I've tried a few things from research and what other threads have suggested:
- Reinstalling Xcode and my operating system.
- Deleting the ios version from the xCode packages which resulted in a different problem.

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed/15332795

Comment: Having same problem on XCode 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with iOS 12.1 and xcode 10.1 on MacOS 10.14.1. I tried all the other methods provided by various sources. The one suggested by jblaauboer above is the only solutions that actually worked. It is not the xcode application itself, but some other configurations associated it caused this problem. Reinstallation of xcode from app store after a clean uninstall using CleanMyMac 3 resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I have upgraded & added new Xcode 11.2.1 from old Xcode 10.2.1.

Steps to follow (Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0):

1. Open Devices and Simulators
2. Remove your device from the list
3. Tap the + button on the bottom left of the window
4. Select the device (before tapping Trust on it)
5. Tap Trust on the device

After this if you get same error then do following:

I have just copied additional iOS DeviceSupport from Xcode 11.2.1 and added to Xcode 10.2.1 and error gets solve for me.

(Note: While doing this please quite Xcode and then try to run)

Path: ⁨MacOS⁩ ▸ ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨Xcode 10.2.1.app⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨Platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨iPhoneOS.platform⁩ ▸ ⁨DeviceSupport⁩

Comment: I have not updgraded, still on 10.2.1 and having the error.  I tried your steps, and they have not resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just running out of disc space (Xcode 10.1, iOS 13.3). Everything was fine after I made some space.

The error message might be misleading.