# There is an error of `dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed` running app at iOS9.0.2 by Xcode10.1(10B61)

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode10.1

There is a problem that I use Xcode10.1(10B61) running app at iOS9.0.2.
Here is the information : dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed) doesn't work for me, who has the good solution?

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed/15332795

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, couldn't get symbols from any devices running iOS 9.x under Xcode 10.1 (10B61), solutions for me was side installing Xcode 9.4.1 and using it to obtain symbols, after that i could use my older devices with Xcode 10 again.

You can find older Xcode versions here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete a directory in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`
   that matches the version of the iOS on your device.
2. Restart Xcode.