# dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed for iPhone XS Max running ios 12.1.2

Tags: ios, ios12, iphone-xs-max

I am trying to run my app on iPhone XS Max running iOS 12.1.2, but till the end of the build and it returns "dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed" , i removed the supported files for it and rerun my app and it gives the same error , any suggestions i'm stuck ?????

Comment: I got this error after I ran out of space. After I emptied the drive, restarted my mac then did exactly as @JMiguel mentioned, especially "step 3 and 4".
It solved the problem permanently.

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed/15332795

Comment: This answer is simple and worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/58929334/1919317

Answer (score 5):

There is a (temporary) solution I've been using...

1. Open Devices and Simulators
2. Remove your device from the list
3. Tap the + button on the bottom left of the window
4. Select the device (before tapping Trust on it)
5. Tap Trust on the device
6. Profit

For me I still have to do this steps every time I connect the device...

Answer (score 0):

I have both Xcode10.3 and Xcode11.2.1 installed on same machine. Whatever solution I try, it doesn't work with Xcode10.3 and iPhone11. It works like a charm on the latest Xcode though. I think the solution is to switch to the latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this issue by installing Xcode 11.2 and 10.1 alongside each other, and using Xcode 11.2 to build the debugger files. It seems 10.1 can't handle newer versions of iOS and builds the debugger support files incorrectly.

Delete everything under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/` related to the version of iOS giving you trouble. This is where Xcode saves the debugger support files. Then launch Xcode 11.2 with the phone connected and allow it to build the debugger support. After it has finished, close it and open Xcode 10.1 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i tried everything and my solution was go to app store and download again xcode, he is going to updated by self

Answer (score 0):

try Run it in latest Xcode version then try again in the version you want
and try to reboot the mobile device and unpair it and connect it again thats worked for me

BTW thanks @unstablerealtiy