# dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed for 6s plus running on iOS 13.1.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, ios13

I am trying to run AR Project in device it gives me an dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed error. My system OS is Mojave 10.14.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107715/dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed-for-iphone-xs-max-running-ios-12-1-2)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770751/xcode-organizer-can-not-use-iphone-dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed) answer. But still having the same issue, Not able to run my application. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have fixed it, answered it with step by step easy guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/78096637/11834626

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because somehow older versions of Xcode have an issue creating these cache files properly - try below:

- Close Xcode
- Install the device support profile that matches your iOS version from [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/)
- Go to: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/<your device's OS version name>/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/`

  *Note: if you don't have this folder, run Xcode, connect your device and try to pair with it - the folder should be created by then ...*
- Create these three empty files - overwrite existing ones if any:

```
 .copied_dyld_shared_extract_dylibs
 .processed_dyld_shared_extract_dylibs
  dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs
```

- Start Xcode again

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue I has in xCode 10.1.

In order to solve this issue the three files that you must be in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/<your device's OS version name>/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/` are:

- dyld_shared_cache_arm64e
- .copied_dyld_shared_cache_arm64e
- .processed_dyld_shared_cache_arm64e

I didn't create empty files, I copied and pasted this three files from previous OS version folder in `/Caches/com.apple.dyld/`. If you just upgrade to 13.4.1 iOs versión, I copy from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.4.1 (17E262)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above solutions with no success.

Finally, simply unpairing the device and pairing it again fixed the issue for me.

see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0